# Convert columns into matrix

Tags: text-processing, awk

I've got a script to get the following results
1st Column: Slot number
2nd Column: Port number
3rd Column: Number of connections

```
1 1 23,        
1 2 0,        
1 3 38,        
1 4 34,    
2 1 8,   
2 2 18,   
2 3 0,   
2 4 22,   
4 1 6,   
4 2 18,   
4 3 10,   
4 4 22,
```

Now, the question is how do I transpose it into a prettier matrix (Rows x Slots)
like below.

```
         Slot #
      1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |           
P  1| 23| 8 | - | 6 |
o  2| 0 | 18| - | 18|
r  3| 38| 0 | - | 10|
t  4| 34| 22| - | 22|
#
```

I would think that using awk would be the way to go, but not sure on how to start it.

Comment: Got it to display what i want using pr

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what you are asking for is a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) (aka a [cross tabulation or crosstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cross_tabulation&redirect=no)). For example with [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/index.html#Top)

```
datamash -sW crosstab 2,1 unique 3 < file
    1   2   4
1   23, 8,  6,
2   0,  18, 18,
3   38, 0,  10,
4   34, 22, 22,
```

If you want to remove the trailing commas from your data, a simple option would be `tr`

```
tr -d , < file | datamash -sW crosstab 2,1 unique 3
    1   2   4
1   23  8   6
2   0   18  18
3   38  0   10
4   34  22  22
```

If you want to add the "missing" column, you need to supply filler data - either

```
{ tr -d , < file ; printf '3 %d -\n' {1..4} ; } | 
  datamash -sW crosstab 2,1 unique 3
    1   2   3   4
1   23  8   -   6
2   0   18  -   18
3   38  0   -   10
4   34  22  -   22
```

or supply just a single point and let `datamash` fill the rest

```
{ tr -d , < file ; printf '3  1 -\n' ; } | 
  datamash --no-strict --filler=- -sW crosstab 2,1 unique 3
    1   2   3   4
1   23  8   -   6
2   0   18  -   18
3   38  0   -   10
4   34  22  -   22
```

Answer (score 1):

used pr | column -t to display what I wanted. Added more of my results to show the full matrix. I figured that the 1st and 2nd columns were redundant and removed it from my dataset. So test_3.txt only contains the data results from the 3rd column.

```
pr -ts" " --columns 9 test_3.txt | column -t
23  8   6   11  18  33  39  16  33
0   18  18  32  18  16  27  13  12
38  0   10  10  21  16  24  16  29
34  22  22  20  16  16  33  21  21
33  23  19  16  13  10  29  16  53
33  19  8   21  10  13  21  17  29
43  31  20  19  14  15  15  0   9
```